# Emoji became invisible in Google Chrome bookmarks and address bar

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

After a recent Windows 10 update, emoji became invisible in Google Chrome bookmarks and address bar. How do I fix that?

I compared the font `seguiemj.ttf` to a backup of that file that I happen to have from when emoji were visible. The files are identical, i.e. the font hasn't changed.

Here's a screenshot of a bookmarks folder whose name (now invisible but taking up space on the right side of the folder icon) is an emoji:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: More global problem (not only in Chrome): https://superuser.com/questions/1813756/unicode-characters-became-invisible-since-windows-10-update/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### TL;DR: A font in a different folder with a different file name (`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\google_emoji_font_for_windows.ttf` from [here](https://github.com/perguto/Country-Flag-Emojis-for-Windows/)) probably was overriding `%WINDIR%\Fonts\seguiemj.ttf` due to having the same font name (`Segoe UI Emoji Regular`).

The following solution from https://github.com/perguto/Country-Flag-Emojis-for-Windows/issues/9 helped me (emphasis mine):

> Ah sorry, the September 23 update for Windows 10 & 11 seems to have broken the font, making all emojis invisible. To revert to the original Windows emojis, just **restore the seguiemj.ttf file (by dragging it to the Windows fonts folder or double-clicking it and pressing "Install") and restart your PC.**
>
> This seems to be the relevant update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/september-26-2023-windows-configuration-update-542780c2-594c-46cb-979d-11116fe164ba#ID0EPBH-button
>
> Microsoft seems to have made rather deep changes to the emoji rendering algorithm (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/colr#colr-version-1-rendering-algorithm) so I have no idea how to fix it, sorry

Before restoring `seguiemj.ttf` and rebooting, I **deleted `google_emoji_font_for_windows.ttf` from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\`**. I also had `google_emoji_font_for_windows_0.ttf` in that folder (maybe I installed `google_emoji_font_for_windows.ttf` twice) but couldn't delete it. After the problem was solved, I could delete it (and did that just in case).

When going to `C:\Windows\Fonts` -> `Segoe UI Emoji Regular` -> right click -> Properties, it said `seguiemj.ttf`. Maybe `google_emoji_font_for_windows.ttf` (also named `Segoe UI Emoji Regular`) in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\` was overriding that default font.