# Unicode characters became invisible since Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, fonts, unicode, emoji

After a recent Windows 10 update, emoji became invisible in several apps (Google Chrome, MS Word).

The behavior of MS Word is particularly weird: When I open a DOCX file that contains emoji (set with the font `Segoe UI Emoji`), they are invisble. After I save it as PDF, emoji become visible also in the DOCX file. But if I then save the DOCX file, close it, and open it again, the emoji are invisible again.

I compared the font `seguiemj.ttf` to a backup of that file that I happen to have from when emoji were visible. The files are identical, i.e. the font hasn't changed.

Deleting the `FontCache` folder didn't help.

What should I try to fix this?

Comment: @KJ Thanks. Just to sum up the links so far: [Your link 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/emoji-not-available-after-upgrade-to-windows-11/b733bc7d-4bb1-4964-baeb-34256b7621e6) lists attempts that didn't work. [Your link 2](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-access-new-emoji-windows-11/) is about a different topic and requires Windows 11. [Your link 3](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/emoji-panel-not-working-windows-10) is about a very different problem (the emoji panel does not appear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### TL;DR: A font in a different folder with a different file name (`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\google_emoji_font_for_windows.ttf` from [here](https://github.com/perguto/Country-Flag-Emojis-for-Windows/)) probably was overriding `%WINDIR%\Fonts\seguiemj.ttf` due to having the same font name (`Segoe UI Emoji Regular`).

The following solution from https://github.com/perguto/Country-Flag-Emojis-for-Windows/issues/9 helped me (emphasis mine):

> Ah sorry, the September 23 update for Windows 10 & 11 seems to have broken the font, making all emojis invisible. To revert to the original Windows emojis, just **restore the seguiemj.ttf file (by dragging it to the Windows fonts folder or double-clicking it and pressing "Install") and restart your PC.**
>
> This seems to be the relevant update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/september-26-2023-windows-configuration-update-542780c2-594c-46cb-979d-11116fe164ba#ID0EPBH-button
>
> Microsoft seems to have made rather deep changes to the emoji rendering algorithm (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/colr#colr-version-1-rendering-algorithm) so I have no idea how to fix it, sorry

Before restoring `seguiemj.ttf` (whic) and rebooting, I **deleted `google_emoji_font_for_windows.ttf` from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\`**. I also had `google_emoji_font_for_windows_0.ttf` in that folder (maybe I installed `google_emoji_font_for_windows.ttf` twice) but couldn't delete it. After the problem was solved, I could delete it (and did that just in case).

When going to `C:\Windows\Fonts` -> `Segoe UI Emoji Regular` -> right click -> Properties, it said `seguiemj.ttf`. Maybe `google_emoji_font_for_windows.ttf` (also named `Segoe UI Emoji Regular`) in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\` was overriding that default font.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27gmI-BEjYU
The second solution in this video solved my problem, unfortunately I can no longer see the flags.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem for me. Do you even have the same problem as I do? Because your link doesn't mention that kind of problem.

Comment: I'm upvoting because this answer put the country-flag emojis on my radar, and that made me look into https://github.com/perguto/Country-Flag-Emojis-for-Windows again (linked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1062418/how-do-i-replace-windows-10s-emoji)) while I was looking for alternative 'windows fonts with emoji'. And that link led me to [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1815647/498103).